# How to send a test deep link in urban airship

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Im having issues trying to find out how to send a test deep link message via urban airship.

In my production urban airship account I can clearly see a section where i can create messages with deep links:

[image]

But in my development urban airship account there is no section to add this deep link message - the only access I have is to a basic test harness like below:

[image]

Do you not have access to the deep linking options for a reason? 
Im assuming I could even send a deep link by modifying the raw payload - but i cant see any docs on this.

Can someone point me into the right direction in regards to this - would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please try this http://docs.urbanairship.com/user-guide/message-composer.html

Comment: I have read it, it's not very helpful to answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pre-configure a deeplink for it to appear as an option (both in production and test). To do so go to the Settings (at the bottom of the left panel) and then Configuration. Make sure that in the "Composer configuration" "Landing Page, Deep Link, URL, and Add Tags" is ON. Under the Deep link tab press "News deep link". The name is what will appear later on in the message composer and the url is what information you'll want to send to the app through the notification. Read more bout it here: http://docs.urbanairship.com/user-guide/message-composer.html#configure-deep-links

For the iOS implementation read this: http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/ios-deep-linking.html#customizing-the-deep-link-action

Comment: I know that's the case for production but this does not make the option show up on dev. I still get the test harness

Comment: The development app and production app works exactly the same the only difference is the destination. If you want to test deep link notification you shouldn't use the "Test Push" in Settings but the Message composer. On the iOS side you should set the  UAConfig's "setDetectProvisioningMode" to YES, then running your app on a ios device UA will detect that you are running under debug mode and will only receive notification sent from the Development app on the UA side.

Comment: The problem is that the Message composer is not coming up on my dev account (only on the production account). Could be some sort of licence issue where I need to contact sales?

Comment: or you don't have the team permission

Comment: potentially - i cant mark the above as the answer because its not

Comment: also whats weird is that my login is "Administrator" so you would think i would have access to the message composer by default.

Comment: You have supplied enough info for me to mark this as the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the 'extra' param in the payload on the 'Test Push' page (https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/.../test/push/#ios). UA uses the key "^d" for deeplinks:

```
{
    "audience": {
        "device_token": "..."
    },
    "notification": {
        "alert": "Test",
        "ios": {
            "extra": {"^d":"..."},
            "badge": 0
        }
    },
    "device_types": [
        "ios"
    ]
}
```